# this.Retrieve method is executed

Tags: reverse-proxy

**On executing the below code this.onRetrivefailed is executed. Here we are using reverse proxy,so can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue.**

$(document).ready(function () {
   SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { retrieveListItems(); });
});

function retrieveListItems() {

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml(
    '<View><Query><Where>' +
  '<Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Author\' /><Value Type=\'Integer\'><UserID Type=\'Integer\' /></Value></Eq></Where></Query>' +
    '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
);
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRetrieveSucceeded),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRetrieveFailed)
);
```

}

Comment: Please include the error message from `onRetrieveFailed` (second argument, and `get_message`)